# How do I prove that $\Vert u \times v\rVert = \lVert u\rVert\lVert v\rVert\sin(\theta)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, cross-product

I already know the following properties

$$\langle u, u\rangle = \lVert u\rVert^2$$

and
$$\langle u\times v, w\rangle = \langle u ,v\times w\rangle$$

However, I am unable to use these properties in order to prove the above property in the question.

Comment: What is your definition of $u\times v$?  (The property in the question could be part of the definition.)  $\\$Note:  $<u,u>$ is dot (scalar) product, not cross (vector) product

Comment: I think you need to verify the identity
$$||u\times v||^2+\langle u,v\rangle^2=||u||^2\,||v||^2.$$ Not an enjoyable task, I'm afraid. But straightforward. Of course, you might go via the way of quaternions and the four square identity.

Comment: Cf. [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity)

Answer (score 0):

- If $\vec u$ or $\vec v$ is the zero vector, then $\left\lVert\vec u\right\rVert=0$, or $\left\lVert\vec v\right\rVert=0$ by the positive definiteness norm axiom.

Clearly $\vec u\times\vec v$ is also the zero vector, so $\left\lVert\vec u\times \vec v \right\rVert=0$.

Hence, equality $\left\lVert \vec u \times \vec v\right\rVert = \lVert \vec u\rVert\lVert \vec v\rVert\sin \theta$ holds.

- If both $\vec u$ or $\vec v$ are non-zero vectors, then we have

$$
\begin{align}
\left\lVert \vec u \times \vec v\right\rVert^2
&=\left\lVert\vec u\right\rVert^2\left\lVert\vec v\right\rVert^2−(\vec u\cdot\vec v)^2\\
&=\left\lVert\vec u\right\rVert^2\left\lVert\vec  v\right\rVert^2−\left\lVert\vec  u\right\rVert^2\left\lVert\vec  v\right\rVert^2 \cos^2\theta\\
&=\left\lVert\vec  u\right\rVert^2\left\lVert\vec  v\right\rVert^2(1−\cos^2\theta)\\
&=\left\lVert\vec  u\right\rVert^2\left\lVert\vec  v\right\rVert^2\sin^2\theta
\end{align}
$$
$$\implies\left\lVert \vec u \times \vec v\right\rVert = \left\lVert \vec u\right\rVert\left\lVert \vec v\right\rVert\sin \theta$$
since square of real number is non-negative.